# Cannot convert 'nan' to double error when using QGIS field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, error

I am using the formula:

```
($perimeter -sqrt($perimeter^2 - 16 * $area)) /4
```

to calculate the width of irregular polygons in a layer. However, I get an error

> "cannot convert 'nan' to double"

I have looked at other stackoverflow reports on this error but cannot make it run correctly. I have tried changing the output type and the field length with no avail.

[image]

Comment: somewhere you are dividing by 0 or taking the sqrt of a negative number or some such issue - try checking the inputs to your equation

Comment: @MrXsquared it is a polygon layer and the $perimeter and $area should be inherently calculated from qgis, so they are not calling upon attribute columns (to my understanding). All of the features have valid geometries, so I don't understand how this could be an issue. I don't know how sharing any data would help.

Comment: What other “stackoverflow reports” have you looked at?  Please provide links to them within the body of your question.

Comment: just try to calculate this `$perimeter^2 - 16 * $area` and see if there are any negative values

Comment: I managed to reproduce error: if there are polygons similar to circles, the expression `$perimeter ^2 - 16 * $area` is negative !!!

Answer (score 8):

The expression returns the error if there were circles or polygons very similar to circles among the polygons;
in fact assuming the presence of a circle:

`(2*pi*r)^2 < 16*pi*r^2`

`pi(4*pi*r^2) < 4(4*pi*r^2)`

that is `pi < 4`

[image]

**EDIT1**:

To prevent the error from appearing you can use the expression:

```
try(
   ($perimeter -sqrt($perimeter^2 - 16 * $area)) /4
   ,0)
```

which will calculate the expression in all polygons except the ones that generate error ((in these polygons, it will always return 0).

`try function`: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#try

**EDIT2**:

you also need to pay attention to the number of digits after the comma (for the perimeter and area) because the difference `$perimeter^2-16*$area` could be negative, so I also suggest this solution:

```
with_variable('perim', round($perimeter,1),
try(
    (@perim-sqrt((@perim)^2 - 16*round($area,1)))/4
 ,0))
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. I know you said "assuming" presence of a circle. My polygons are definitely not circles (but QGIS thinks they are). Do you know how I could Identify which polygons it thinks are circles and then exclude them from this calculation?

Comment: @hcf, I added a possible solution to the answer to prevent the calculation from freezing.